# JUnit expectation failure on verify

Tags: java, junit, junit4, easymock

I am trying to JUnit test using EasyMock. I am facing assertion error in the setter line in which argument is populated from another private method. Below is the code and JUnit failure error.

My JUnit class:

```
private EasyMockSupport easyMockSupport = new EasyMockSupport();
private ObjectOne easymockObject= easyMockSupport.createMock(ObjectOne .class);
// creating employeelist
easymockObject.setEmployee(employeelist);
```

MyClass

```
ObjectOne methodOne(ObjectOne obj, List<Employee> employeeList) {

    obj.setEmployee(getEmployeeList(employeeList));
    return obj;
}

private List<Employee> getEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {

    Employee emp = null;
    for (Employee employee: employeeList) {
        if ("somename".equalsIgnoreCase(employee.getName())) {
            emp = new Employee();
            emp.setName(employee.getName());
            break;
        }
    }
    return emp;
}
```

I am getting assertion error for the line:

```
obj.setEmployee(getEmployeeList(employeeList));
```

because `Employee` does not override `hashCode` and `equals` method. Though the employee count size is same but the objects are different its failing. Any suggestion how to handle this without overriding `hashCode` and `equals` method in `Employee` class.

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call ObjectOne.setEmployee([Employee@528c868]):
    ObjectOne.setEmployee([Employee@64c63c79]): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Comment: Please note: my answer will solve your problem; but your real problem is that the above code doesn't make much sense at all; it is wrong on many levels: a non-static method like methodOne() should **not** work on some other ObjectOne object; so passing in/returning another ObjectOne is confusing. Then naming: avoid using "list/set/map" in names - don't specify the type of collection in your names - as that might change. Just call it **employees" for example. Then `getEmployeeList()` ... are you sure that the code is correct? It should return a LIST, but returns a single employee object!

Comment: Finally: you really **want** that your employee class implements equals and hashCode. Because: you really do not want to have **other classes** contain logic like the above where you do getName() and to make a comparison / decision based on that. And of course: your names are really misleading. Example your "getEmplyList()" could be called "fetchEmployeeWithGivenName()" - making it clear that it is about finding a specific employee.

Comment: Finally:  it is **really good** that you look into unit tests. But: find people to review your code. Constantly. Because unit tests alone will not fix your bad coding practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could as well use

```
Capture<List<Employee>> employeeCapture = new Capture<>();
easymockObject.setEmployee(capture(employeeCapture));
```

In the assert part use

```
employeeCapture.getValue()
```

to do the assertions.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the expected behavior:

```
easymockObject.setEmployee(employeelist);
```

you are implicitly instructing EasyMock to expect that exactly that object employeelist will be passed to this call.

But obviously, your production code is passing **some** other list to ObjectOne.

So, what you can do is to weaken that condition, like in

```
easymockObject.setEmployee(EasyMock.notNull(List.class))
```

Now EasyMock will accept any non-null list to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer from this link http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification. We have to use argument matchers to handle this issue. In this link refer the section **Flexible Expectations with Argument Matchers**